# How to disable default desktop background picture module with third-party window manager?

Tags: window-manager, desktop-background, icewm

I installed latest Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, then installed IceWM and set it as a default window manager. Everything works just great, IceWM's background picture is set in the config and is displayed properly, but from time to time, after few hours or sometimes days, the background picture set by IceWM disappears and Ubuntu's original purple background picture is displayed. How to fix this?

The problem is that I do not know how Ubuntu handles background picture, maybe I could kill or disable the program that displays the backround in Ubuntu, but I do not know what that program is. Ideally I'd want Ubuntu never disrupt the work o IceWM and leave it alone.